# Product reference field (autocomplete) length limitation

Tags: commerce

I use taxonomy based pricing calculations with rules. There are 4 differrent taxonomy vocbularies used as taxonomy reference field. So  when I "bulk generate" the products, I become 1152 product variations. The field "product reference" on product display node is limited to 2048 characters so it is not possible to reffer all my 1152 variations. How to extend the limitation of product reference field?

Answer (score 1):

This limitation takes affect only when the product reference field widget ist set to "autocomplete". Set up the "product reference field" to checkboxes, list or turn of the widget when you use "bulk add" product